# A CSS margin does not work as expected in my HTML

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
}

.div2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.div3 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In above code I have a confusion, because in above code the margin was not affected to the inner div tags. What might be the problem?

[Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJsu5.png)

and what I want to do is

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkDKZ.png)

Comment: [LearnLayout.com](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: You're misunderstanding margins. A margin-bottom: 0; would not put the div to the bottom of whatever it's in. I'd definitely check out the link @Paulie_D posted.

Comment: You should check 4 answers below and solve your problem but I suggest you to learn CSS layout and position before trying them.

Comment: well if you keep being downvoted, instead of begging for understanding, maybe you could try to ask better questions, don't you think ?

Comment: `it cause me banned for 2-3 days for asking a new question so please help and thank in advance.` --> and within these 2/3 days you can read some tutorial to understand how HTML/CSS works

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `float` and `position: relative/absolute` settings in the combination and with the settings shown below to achieve the desired result shown in your image.

Note: All this has nothing to do with margins.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
}

.div2 {
float: right;
position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;

}

.div3 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**No need to use `margin` , just use `position` property.**

**Here is the Snippet.**

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.div1 {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.div2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.div3 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div3"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired o/p with margin this should be your code

```
div {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .div1 {
        height: 600px;
        width: 600px;
    }

    .div2 {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: 300px;
        margin-top: 0px; 
    }

    .div3 {
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 150px;
    }
```

But, this would be a wrong approach, the right approach is to manipulate positioning the inner divs to left or right. This is because of the concept of box model. You learn more about box-model to better understand when to use margin-l/r/t/b and when to use positioning

Correct Code :

```
div {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .div1 {
            height: 600px;
            width: 600px;
            position : relative;
        }

        .div2 {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            position : absolute;
            right : 0;
        }

        .div3 {
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            position : absolute;
            bottom : 0;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `position: absolute;` and then in place of `margin-left` or `margin-top` use `left` or `top` or `bottom`

```css
div {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .div1 {
            height: 600px;
            width: 600px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .div2 {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            right: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .div3 {
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="div2">
            <div class="div3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps